# Loading large Visual FoxPro files are very slow. C#(OleDB)

Tags: c#, visual-foxpro

I want to load large .DBF (Visual FoxPro) files into a DataTable.
For smaller files < 300MB it works fine with a fill command, and it runs pretty fast.
But for larger file I run out of memory and need to load them into smaller parts.
(Loading row 0...1000, then 1001..2000 and so on)

Based on some code found on the internet I made this operation, input start is the row to start reading from and max is the number of rows that I want to read.

The problem is that even if I just want to read 5 rows it takes around 30-60seconds on my machine due to the very slow execution of the Command.ExecuteReader.

```
  public DataTable LoadTable2(string folder, string table, int start, int max)
  {
        string ConnectionString = "Provider=vfpoledb.1;Data Source="+folder+"\\"+table;
        OleDbConnection Connection = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString);
        Connection.Open();
        string dataString = String.Format("Select * from {0}", table);
        OleDbCommand Command = new OleDbCommand(dataString, Connection);
        //Takes very long time on large files.
        OleDbDataReader Reader = Command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        var dt = ds.Tables.Add(table);
        // Add the table columns. 
        for (int i = 0; i < Reader.FieldCount; i++)
        {
           dt.Columns.Add(Reader.GetName(i), Reader.GetFieldType(i));
        }
        int intIdx = 0;
        int cnt = 0;
        while (Reader.Read())
        {
           if (intIdx >= start)
           {
              DataRow r = dt.NewRow();
              // Assign DataReader values to DataRow.  
              for (int i = 0; i < Reader.FieldCount; i++)
                 r[i] = Reader[i];
              dt.Rows.Add(r);
              cnt++;
           }
           if (cnt >= max)
           {
              break;
           }
           intIdx++;
        }
        Reader.Close();
        Connection.Close();
        return dt;
  }
```

I have tested with both OLE and ODBC connection, no big difference.
Files are all on local disc.

Does anyone have a good idea for how to make this much faster?

Best regards
Anders

Comment: This is why we have pagination.

Comment: As Mark mentioned in his answer to query by some key... Does  the table you are querying from have some auto-increment ID you can work based on?  If that has an index, that would help too.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that with that driver (VFPOLEDB), you can change your query to specify the record numbers of interest.  That way it would not be necessary to read through a bunch of records to get to the starting point.  It would then not be necessary to skip over any records; just read the entire requested result set.  The query might look like this:

```
SELECT * from thetable where recno() >= 5000 and recno() <= 5500
```

I realized that I have this driver installed and just now tested it and it does work.  However, I don't think it "optimizes" that statement.  In theory, it could directly compute the record offsets using record numbers, but (based on simple observation of a query on a larger dbf), it seems to do a full table scan. However, with FoxPro, you could create an index on `recno()`, and then it would be optimized.

Comment: Hi Mark thnaks, the statement is working regardig the results, but not speed. The FoxPro files are generated from a program that I can not modify.:(

Comment: If you can't use an indexed field or create an index, then it seems like you might be out of luck.  There might be something that could be done with the `execscript` function and executing some kind of native VFP command to retrieve the data.  I'm not sure.

Comment: Just as a follow up: We went for a small foxpro program that converts the .dbf into .csv files that can be uploaded into the SQL db faster.